# Populating one column's cells based on another column

Tags: excel, vba

One worksheet. 103 columns. I need to populate a 104th column that looks in one column (Column O aka. 15).  The column only has two values in it, either a 1 or a 3. If that column has a 1 in it then the 104th column cell for that row needs one notation; if it's a 3 then it needs a different notation. I know a little about formulas and a little about vba, which has gotten me nowhere with this. I have other macros that I use to convert values in columns, but they all work within the same column and I can't seem to get those adapted to what I need now.  Is there a relatively quick little macro that I can run through that just looks up the value in column o and pops in one of two notations to my last column?

Edited the first part there. Thinking of two things at once I guess.  It's columns. There are close to 3600 rows.  I need to run through each row and enter a notation in the last column(104th) based off of whether the value in Column O is a 1 or 3. So, start with row 1 and enter either an x or y in the last column depending on the value in column o, then repeat for each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub HTH()

    With Range("O1", Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 89)
        .Formula = "=IF(O1=3,""x"",""y"")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: that it presumes the column can only contain a 1 or a 3.  If it can contain other values or blanks then you will need to modify it slightly.  Something like `.Formula = "=IF(O1=3,""y"",IF(O1=1,""x"",""""))"`

Comment: @brett - Thanks, I managed to sneak in before a dirty old loop got pulled out of the toolbox, I'm sure someone had there lid open though! ;)

Comment: Thanks. This does exactly what I needed, and it's good to have the modification for future reference to use with columns that have more than just two values (as I would think many people have).